Laser beam in a lift thought experiment in general relativity
I am reading "Cosmology - A very short Introduction" by P. Coles (2001) and I am a bit confused with a particular part of the text in p.24 about the famous thought experiment involving a laser beam from one side to another in an accelerating lift. The text at some point says:

An observer outside the lift who is at rest sees the lift accelerate away, but if he could see the beam from outside it would still be straight.

The author then continues to say that for an observer inside the lift the light would bend etc. My question is why does the outside observer see a straight beam if the lift is accelerating relative to him? Shouldn't he see the light beam hit a lower point on the other side of the lift since the lift is moving vertically and the laser beam horizontally relative to him?

The outside observer would see the laser beam straight, meaning that the photons, from his perspective, undergo a "free evolution" with initial condition given by a velocity pointing slightly upwards (due to the lift's motion). But once a photon is emitted and propagates through the vacuum in the lift, it moves in a straight line. It still hits slightly "lower" in the lift, because the lift accelerates. For the inside observer, there is no "upwards" motion, but the acceleration is still there.

So both the inside and the outside observers should see the light hitting a lower point at the other side of the lift? That's why I am confused.

@Floyd Yes, that is correct

The statement in the quote is incorrect. The outside observer will see each emitted photon flying straight, obviously, because, once emitted, the photon no longer has anything to do with the ship or its acceleration. This however doesn't make “the beam” straight. Imagine a rotating sprinkler. It emits spiral jets while each drop of water is flying straight. Meanwhile the inside observer will see each photon moving along a curved line.

In the sentence that you quote "straight" means "in a straight line". The observer at rest outside of the lift sees the light beam move horizontally relative to themselves but this does not mean that the light beam moves horizontally relative to the lift (if the direction of the lift's acceleration is vertical).
